# Get time in seconds since epoch in Tcl for a specific time

Tags: tcl, clock

I am trying to convert a date/time of the following format `YYYYDDMMHHmm` to seconds since epoch in Tcl.

I've tried to do this with the following, but it isn't working:

`clock scan 201403251850 -format %Y%m%d%H%M`

For the above, I am trying to convert `6:50PM on March 25th, 2014` to seconds since epoc.

How can I achieve this?

Chris

Comment: What is the value that you are getting from the above command? I get `1395759000` which seems to be correct to me... The only thing that looks off is that you're asking for `YYYYDDMMHHmm` but using `%Y%m%d%H%M`.

Comment: @Jerry, Hey Jerry, I get an error `bad switch "-format": must be -base, or -gmt while executing`. Isn't `%Y%m%d%H%M` the correct formatting for the input time string?

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce your error. I'm not sure if this has an incidence, but what Tcl version are you using? And you probably meant `YYYYMMDDHHmm` in your question, that's what I was drawing attention to.

Comment: @Jerry, I am at TCL v8.0

Comment: 8.0? That's quite... old. Is it possible to upgrade to at least 8.5?

Comment: @Jerry Unfortunately no... :(

Comment: Hmm, according to [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/clock.htm), you should use `-base` instead of `-format` (apparently, `-format` didn't exist yet in 8.0), which works in a similar way. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Jerry, That doesn't work either `expected integer but got "%Y%m%d%H%M"` I think I will try to find a way to do this calculation in a Unix command from within my Tcl script.

Comment: `-format` was added in 8.5; we got tired of working around bugs in other people's time libraries — especially HPUX if memory serves — and so decided to have just our own bugs from there on. Free-format time parsing is an ill-defined swamp…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on Tcl 8.3.3, so *should* work with 8.0: The regex may need some tweaking to suit the pre-8.1 regexp engine.

```
proc scan_datetime {datetime} {
    # expect a datetime string like "6:50PM on March 25th, 2014"
    regexp {^([0-9]+):([0-9]{2})([AP]M) on ([[:alpha:]]+) ([0-9]{1,2}).., ([0-9]{4})} $datetime -> hr min ampm mon day year
    if {$ampm == "PM"} then {incr hr 12} elseif {$hr == 12} then {set hr 0}
    clock scan "$day $mon $year $hr:$min"
}
puts [clock format [scan_datetime "6:50PM on March 25th, 2014"]]
puts [clock format [scan_datetime "12:34AM on February 1st, 2012"]]
```

```
Tue Mar 25 18:50:00 EDT 2014
Wed Feb 01 00:34:00 EST 2012
```

If the above regular expression doesn't work in 8.0, try this:

```
proc scan_datetime {datetime} {
    set d {[0-9]}
    set a {[A-Za-z]}
    regexp "^($d$d?):($d$d)(\[AP]M) on ($a+) ($d$d?).., ($d$d$d$d)" $datetime -> hr min ampm mon day year
    if {$ampm == "PM"} then {incr hr 12} elseif {$hr == 12} then {set hr 0}
    clock scan "$day $mon $year $hr:$min"
}
```

---

Specifically for the format YYYYmmddHHMM:

```
tcl8.3.3 % set t 201403251452
201403251452
tcl8.3.3 % set d {[0-9]}
[0-9]
tcl8.3.3 % regsub "($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)" $t {\2/\3/\1 \4:\5} tt
1
tcl8.3.3 % clock scan $tt
1395773520
tcl8.3.3 % clock format [clock scan $tt]
Tue Mar 25 14:52:00 EDT 2014
```

Comment: Great answer glenn! I think I can definitely work with this! If it's not too much trouble, could you please explain the `regexp` and `regsub` portions a little? Thanks

Comment: documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/contents.htm -- anything particular you'd like me to explain?

Comment: Particularly the `{\2/\3/\1 \4:\5}` portion. I figured out that it's positioning the `($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d)` portions, but I could not find any documentation on this. Could you please expand a little on how that works? Thanks

Comment: I want to rearrange the date fields into a format that `clock scan` will consume: to transform `YYYYmmddHHMM` into `mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM`. I use capturing parentheses in the pattern. You can refer back to them in the replacement string with `\n` where "n" is 1 for the the first open parenthesis, 2 for the second, etc. This is documented in the `regsub` man page: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/regsub.htm